# Making a REST API call from a Script Activity in Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, automationstudio

We are trying to update a service cloud custom object from marketing cloud.
Can we make a REST api call within a script in Automation Studio.It will be great if someone in this forum can confirm they have already done it.

Comment: Why use the REST API, when there are AMPscript functions for updating SF objects from SFMC?

Comment: Hi Adam,Thanks. We do not want to use cloud page ,We are trying to do this as a scheduled activity through Automation .Can we achieve that through AMPscript functions ?

Comment: I'm not referring to CloudPages.  You include content areas or blocks that contain AMPscript with using SSJS .  See the [SSJS Content Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentFunctions.htm) for details.

Answer (score 14):

I've done a REST API call from a Script Activity.  Here's an example:

```
<script type="javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core","1.1.5");

var DE = "Contacts_To_Delete";
var logDE = "Contacts_To_Delete_Log";
var log = DataExtension.Init(logDE);

/* for legacy API component package */
var url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken';

/* for newest API component packages */
/* var url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v2/token'; */

var contentType = 'application/json';

var payload = {
  "grant_type":"client_credentials",
  "client_id":"YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
  "client_secret":"YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
  "account_id":"YOUR_MID"
};

var authRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
var statusCode = authRequest["StatusCode"];
var response = authRequest["Response"][0];
var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response).accessToken;

url = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts";
url += "/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference";
var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];

var payload = {
     "deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes",
     "targetList": {
       "listType": {
         "listTypeID": 3
       },
       "listKey": DE 
     },
   "deleteListWhenCompleted": false,
   "deleteListContentsWhenCompleted": true
};

try {

  var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
  result = Stringify(result).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
  log.Rows.Add({"Message": "result: " + result});

} catch (e) {

  e = Stringify(e).replace(/[\n\r]/g, '')
  log.Rows.Add({"Message": "error: " + e});

}

</script>
```

Comment: To speed up the REST call in a script, you can set up another automation to get the access token and write it to a DE every 45 min (if legacy, 45min just to be safe). Then before you make api call just retrieve the token from that DE, I believe retrieve a row in a DE that only contains 1 row should be faster than an HTTP call to get access token.

Comment: In addition, why do you wrote the whole payload as a string since SSJS allows JSON handling? I think it's better to have a JSON payload and then in the Post function use the function Stringify to send a string version of that payload.

Comment: @DarleisonRodrigues It's b/c I'm a JS noob.  Feel free to re-write it as your own answer. You'll certainly get an upvote from me if you did.

Comment: @tkhuynh Under normal circumstances, automations can run at a minimum of every hour.  New REST tokens are only good for around 20 minutes.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs you are correct about automation run at a minimum of 1 hour. However, there is wait time activity. What you would do is to have the automation run every hour with 3 activities: 1st is script activity, 2nd wait activity for 45 min, 3rd is the same script activity as the 1st one. With V2 REST token which expires in ~18 min. So I would set up 1 hour run automation with: scritpt, wait 15min, script, wait 15min, script, wait 15, script.Hope this answers your concern