# Using External API to generate unique link invitation

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, postman

Before anything, this questions is from a beginner in the API environment, so any feedback is greatly welcome.

I have a request to create an invitation URL for customers to leave a service review on Trustpilot. This URL generated by Trustpilot will be used as the link in an email, which will be sent to a Data Extension.

I managed to generate the URL in Postman for an individual contact, as in below:

```
POST /v1/private/product-reviews/business-units/123456789abcd/invitation-links HTTP/1.1
Host: api.trustpilot.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer hdsjahdSKDJKJSJDkkd
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 76a6b8db-4a4c-4082-be0a-3473ef4f7fc9,c511b743-35f9-4256-b8ca-087f3d9af977
Host: api.trustpilot.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 584
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

{
  "referenceId": "InviteTest",
  "locale": "en-ie",
  "products": [
    {
      "sku": "4121",
      "name": "T-shirt",
      "mpn": "4121",
      "imageUrl": "https://www.brand.com/product/image.jpg",
      "productUrl": "https://www.brand.com/theproduct",
      "gtin": "01234567890",
      "brand": "Brand"
    }
  ],
  "consumer": {
    "email": "consumeremail@gmail.com",
    "name": "Luiz Fernando"
  },
  "redirectUri": "https://www.brand.com"
}
```

But this is for one email only and it's in Postman, so now I need to bring it to the 'real world'. Email and Name should be updated dynamically based on the Data Extension, so that each subscriber gets a unique URL.

I have a bit of AMPScript that gets Name and Email address from the Sendable Data Extension.

```
%%[
VAR
@PersonEmail,
@rows,
@row,
@ReviewerEmail,
@ReviewerFirstName,
@ReviewerLastName,
@ReviewerFullName

/* Get the PersonContactID field from the email - client doesn't use SubscrikerKey */ 
SET @PersonContactID = AttributeValue("Email")

/* Look up Sign Up Data Extension */
SET @rows = LookupRows("CRM Sign Up","Email",@PersonContactId)

IF RowCount(@rows) > 0 THEN
 /* Set the row to reference */
  SET @row = Row(@rows,1)
  SET @ReviewerEmail = Field(@row,"Email")
  SET @ReviewerFirstName = Field(@row,"FirstName")
  SET @ReviewerLastName = Field(@row,"Surname")
  SET @ReviewerFullName = Concat(@ReviewerFirstName, " ", @ReviewerLastName)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Now, how can I actually generate these URLs in Marketing Cloud, so that the payload fetchs name and email from the AMPScript and then generate the unique URL?

Am I even going the right direction here?

Comment: I don't get, that your first API call is to Trustpilot API, and you want to send an email with Ampscript? How are those two systems interlinked?

Comment: Hi Lukas. Sure, sorry it wasn't clear. So, the API call to TrustPilot is only to generate the unique URL , and then this URL will be used as a link in the email sent from Marketing Cloud. I will rephrase my question to make it clearer.

Comment: I would do this outside of the email. Perhaps via a Script Activity prior to send. Putting API calls inside of an email is opening up many risks that could affect your sending including time-outs or delayed sends

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington, that makes sense. I've found another thread that goes alongside what you suggested so I will try it using a script activity. 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224218/making-a-rest-api-call-from-a-script-activity-in-automation-studio