# How does SFMC calls third party API using SSL Certificate

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ssl

We want to establish a secure connection between Salesforce Marketing Cloud and MuleSoft through SSL certificate.
We will give Public key to mule to import certificate, MuleSoft will import that public key on there end so whenever there is call from SFMC through private key MuleSoft will check /understand we have certificate for this through trust store and allow the connection.

Any suggestion or steps how we will call this API from Salesforce Marketing Cloud ?

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not possible in Marketing Cloud. Unlike when [working with Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_client_certs_http.htm), you can't assign a certificate to a callout in neither AmpScript nor SSJS.

Comment: So without SSL how will I call external API

Comment: It depends on whether it’s soap or rest, and on where you want to call it from. Here is an example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224218/making-a-rest-api-call-from-a-script-activity-in-automation-studio/224222